# \mathsf{} prints digits in serif font

Tags: fonts

I am using `mathsf{}` in a command to mark special kinds of variables in a formula.

I have:

```
\newcommand{\mycmd}[1]{\mathsf{#1}}
```

In formulas I usually have

```
$\mycmd{specialvariable_1} = yada yada yada$
```

Now I noticed that the digits in the subscript are still printed in the serif font.
This also happens for non-subscript numbers. A minimal example is:

```
$\mathsf{a5\,b_3}$
```

here the digits are printed in a serif font, the letters are printed in a sans-serif font.

How to force LaTeX to also print the digits in a sans-serif font?

(Maybe of interest: my command is often nested in other commands that occasionally are themselves nested in other commands...)

**[Update]**
As requested I made a minimal working example. It seems the package `sansmath` is the problem. Without the package, the digits are printed in sans-serif, with the package, the digits are printed with serifs. Nevertheless this seems a bit counterintuitve...

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{sansmath}

\begin{document}
 $\mathsf{a5\,b_3}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please provide an MWE.  This depends on your font set-up and tex engine.  If you use `\showoutput` the log file will tell exactly which fonts are being used.  In a standard article document, the digits inside `\mathsf` _are_ taken from `cmss`, the sans serif font, even when they are subscripts.

Comment: Unfortunately `sansmath` does not redefine the `\mathsf` command.  You just have to put `\sansmath` in the preamble and then all the maths in your document will use the sans fonts.

Comment: If you just want occasional maths symbols in sans, then you don't need `sansmath`.

Comment: @Thruston, I removed the `sansmath` package and now it works as expected. If you post your comment as answer I will accept it as correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `sansmath` package redefines how numbers are handled, making them `\mathord` instead of `\mathalpha`.  It does this because it takes the letters from the slanted sans serif font for math characters under `\sansmath`, and usually you do not want the numbers to be the slanted version, but it is incorrectly affecting the `normal` math version.  Either drop the `sansmath` package or define your command as follows:

```
\newcommand{\mycmd}[1]{\mbox{\sansmath$\mathsf{#1}$}}
```

taking advantage of `\mathsf` working correctly in the `sans` math version.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{sansmath}

\newcommand{\mycmd}[1]{\mbox{\sansmath$\mathsf{#1}$}}

\begin{document}

$x = \mycmd{a5b_3},\quad y \ne \mathsf{a5b_3}$
\end{document}
```