# pgfplots: How can I customize number formatting styles for log plots based on the numbers?

Tags: pgfplots, sans-serif, ticks

We have seen in [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400870/how-to-remove-mantissa-on-semilogarithmic-pgfplots-graph-while-retaining-modifi) how to set the tick numbers on logarithmic axes in a sans serif font when the style is for 10^x numbering.  Pgfplots offers additional options for numbering log ticks, specifically `log ticks with fixed point` and the option to shift from exponents to fixed point selectively depending on the magnitude of the number `\pgfmathprintnumber[std={-2:2}, precision=1]{...}`.

In the first instance, fixed point, the code below produces the following chart:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[log ticks with fixed point,]
 \addplot [domain=1:1000, ultra thick, color=blue] {x^1.5};
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

***Question 1:*** how can we set these tick numbers in a sans serif font (`\mathsf{..}`)?

In the second instance, we desire to use the functionality of `\pgfmathprintnumber[std={-2:2}, precision=1]{...}` to set the numbers beyond 100 in exponential format with the smaller numbers in fixed point, again in a sans font.

***Question 2:*** How can we exploit `std={x:y}` behavior on log axes using san serif fonts?  The desired result might look like the image below (obtained in this case by editing the pdf file directly)

[image]

Comment: You can use to adjust the style to the tick labels with `\pgfplotsset{every tick label/.append style={...}}`, see [How do I change the font size of the axis tick labels in pgfplots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207214/124842). Maybe helpful [\mathsf{} prints digits in serif font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172862/124842)

Comment: @Bobyandbob -- Thanks for this reply, however, I'm not sure it addresses the problem.  The essential matter is that ticks are set in math mode and a require a modification such as  `xticklabel={$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},' for non-log axes as illustrated in the [earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400870/how-to-remove-mantissa-on-semilogarithmic-pgfplots-graph-while-retaining-modifi), but log ticks and their variants introduce some complications.

Comment: Does [How can I change the font family in pgfplots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33329/124842) help?

Comment: I have previously looked at that package (and that post), but sansmath, which is from 2003, provides limited font support. In the end, I am not going to use cmss as my sans family.  The package also seems to have some challenges in shifting between fonts, e.g., reverting to normal math and back.  So, I am seeking a solution that will guide `pgfplots` to call the sans math font that is currently loaded under `unicode-math` (running LuaLaTex).

Comment: @John did you have any luck finding a sane way to make it use current sans font? it's really annoying in beamer to have a different font for plots

Comment: @filippo -- see below, I do have an answer for the first question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Stefan's suggestion to use `\ifdim`, I've added keys for an upper and lower limit (eupper, elower) beyond which an exponent will be used rather than fixed point tick labeling. This code will create exponents for log bases other than 10 and incorporates `\sffamily` for the text font. This comes close to answering **Question 2** above, although it has not truly adjusted the `std={x:y}` functionality of pgfplots.

```
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  elower/.store in=\elower,
  elower=-1,   %% default, so (base)^0 will print as 1
  eupper/.store in=\eupper,
  eupper=1   %% default 
   }

\pgfplotsset{    
log number format basis/.code 2 args={
            \ifdim#2pt>\elower pt
                \ifdim#2pt<\eupper pt
                   \pgfmathparse{#1^(#2)}%
                   $\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}$
                \else
                   $\mathsf{#1^{\pgfmathprintnumber{#2}}}$
                \fi
             \else
                $\mathsf{#1^{\pgfmathprintnumber{#2}}}$
             \fi
},
/tikz/font={\sffamily},
typeset ticklabels with strut,
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[
    elower=-2, 
    eupper=1,
    log basis  x = 5, %% just to illustrate for a base other than 10
    log basis  y = 10,
    xlabel= {Abscissa label [units]}, 
    ylabel= {Ordinate label [units]},
]
 \addplot [domain=0.01:10, ultra thick, color=red] {x^1.5};
  \node[right, fill=white, rectangle, thin, draw] at (0.5,0.01) {log-log};
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{3em}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
     eupper = 3,
     minor x tick num=1, 
     xticklabel={$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber[zerofill, precision=1]{\tick}}$},
     xlabel= {Abscissa label [units]}, 
     ylabel={Ordinate label [units]},
]
 \addplot [domain=0:10, ultra thick,color=blue] {exp(x)};
 \node[right, fill=white, rectangle, thin, draw] at (5,8) {semi-log};
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The examples from this code follow. The font used is Lucida Sans OT (under LuaLatex) and as before there are some unrelated stylistic adjustments to the tick marks and plot sizes.
[image: Log-log and semi-log plots with sans serif tick marks]

Answer (score 3):

The comment from filippo prompted me to look at this again, and I have **an answer to Question 1**.

Fixed point, sans serif, log axis ticks can be achieved using by modification of the approach for 10<sup>n</sup> axes as follows:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{loglogaxis}[
   log number format basis/.code 2 args={$\pgfmathparse{#1^(#2)}\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}$},
 ]
 \addplot [domain=1:1000, ultra thick, color=blue] {x^1.5};
 \end{loglogaxis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

So with this, we have solutions for linear axes, 10<sup>n</sup> in either semi-log or log-log axes, and fixed point on  either semi-log or log axes.  To summarize these (combine as necessary for semi-log):

**Linear axis:**

```
xticklabel={$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
```

**Log axis, 10<sup>n</sup> ticks:**

```
log number format basis/.code 2 args={$\mathsf{#1^{\pgfmathprintnumber{#2}}}$},
```

**Log axis, fixed-point ticks:**

```
log number format basis/.code 2 args={$\pgfmathparse{#1^(#2)}\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}$},
```

We still **lack** a direct solution for **Question 2** above.  However, a brute force approach is possible by simply manually coding the ticks:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[
   xtick = {1, 10, 100, 1000},
   xticklabels={$\mathsf{1}$, $\mathsf{10}$, $\mathsf{100}$, $\mathsf{10^3}$}, 
   ytick = {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000},
   yticklabels={$\mathsf{1}$, $\mathsf{10}$, $\mathsf{100}$, $\mathsf{10^3}$, $\mathsf{10^4}$},        
]
\addplot [domain=1:1000, ultra thick, color=red] {x^1.5};
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

(Note: My figures have a few style options set on the tick marks themselves, which are not displayed here; these are irrelevant to the numbering issue.)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to change the font **in general** to sans serif when you are inside a `tikzpicture` environment, right? (Otherwise it would look quite strange.) Then please find a solution where only inside the environment the font is changed, but not for the "normal" text and math stuff.

And please find also an automated way to create the `ticklabels` as you requested, although this is quite inconsistent and I don't like it.

For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt,varwidth]{standalone}
% needed to execute stuff "automatically"
\usepackage{etoolbox}
    % change fonts to sans serif then `tikzpicture' environment is started
    \BeforeBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{
        \begingroup
            \changeFonts
    }
    % end scope (for font change)
    \AfterEndEnvironment{tikzpicture}{
        \endgroup
    }
\usepackage{sansmath}
    % create a command to switch fonts in `tikzpicture' environments to a
    % sans serif font
    \newcommand*\changeFonts{
        \sffamily\sansmath
    }
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.3,
        % change `log number format basis' so that all numbers below 10^3
        % are written in "fixed" number format and all others in "sci" number
        % format
        log number format basis/.code 2 args={
            \ifdim#2pt<3pt
                \pgfmathparse{10^(#2)}%
                $\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$
            \else
                $10^{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}$
            \fi
        },
    }
\begin{document}
The following plot shows $f(x) = x^{1.5}$.\par

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[
        xlabel=$x$-axis,
        ylabel=$y$-axis,
    ]
        \addplot [domain=1:1000, ultra thick, color=blue] {x^1.5};
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: -Thank you for this.  You raise several points.  I switch the other sans fonts (for labels, etc.) using a command like `\pgfplotsset{/tikz/font={\sffamily}}`, which will point directly to the current sans serif text font.  As I mentioned to Bobyandbob in an earlier comment, the `sansmath` package has limitations in terms of font selection (e.g., aims for cmss), so I have found it problematic (since I am not using different font families loaded under LuaLatex).  However, your code for `log number format` is very interesting, and I will try it out later and follow up.

Answer (score 0):

As a further follow-up, when [sans-serif unicode math fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374250/are-there-opentype-sans-math-fonts-under-development/427729) are available, we may use `fontspec` and `unicode-math` to change the plot fonts, as in the following example. This approach is easier when the axis labels include sans-serif math expressions, especially those with Greek letters.  I've taken the two such fonts and paired them with STIX Two as the main font (not an ideal match, but makes the point).

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}

    \usepackage{pgfplots} 
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

    \pgfplotsset{%
         width=0.9\textwidth,%
         height=0.6\textwidth,%
        every axis/.append style={thick},
        every minor tick/.append style={very thin,black},
        every minor grid/.append style={very thin, color=Snow4},
        every major tick/.append style={thin, black},
        every major grid/.append style={thin, color=Snow4},
        major tick length={1.2em},
        minor tick length={0.5em},
    }

    \usepackage{unicode-math}

    \setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
    \setmathfont[Scale=MatchUppercase, RawFeature = {-ss01, +ss02, +ss08}]{STIX Two Math}  

    \newfontfamily\GFS[Scale=MatchUppercase]{GFS Neohellenic}
    \newfontfamily\FiraGO[Scale=MatchUppercase, RawFeature = {+ss05,+ss06}]{FiraGo}

    \setmathfont[version = Fira, Scale=MatchUppercase]{Fira Math}
    \setmathfont[version = GFSMath, Scale=MatchUppercase]{GFS Neohellenic Math}

    \newcommand*{\Sphinx}{Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow.}

    \begin{document}

    \Sphinx

    \vspace*{1em}

    {
    \mathversion{Fira}\FiraGO

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[
         xlabel= {Abscissa label, $\lambda(\beta)^2$ [units]}, 
         ylabel={Ordinate label, $gf_{\kern-0.05em u}(\pi)$ [units]},
    ]
     \addplot [domain=1:1000, ultra thick, color=blue] {x^1.5};
     \node[right, fill=white, rectangle, thin, draw] at (30,7) {FiraGO, Fira Math};
    \end{loglogaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \mathversion{normal}
    }

    \vspace*{1em}

    \Sphinx

    \[
    \frac{d\Gamma}{dt}  = \iint_{\symcal{S}}  \nabla p \times \nabla \left( \frac{1}{\rho}\right) \cdot d\symbf{A}
    \]

    \vspace*{1em}


    {
    \mathversion{GFSMath}\GFS
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[
         xlabel= {Abscissa label, $\lambda(\beta)^2$  [units]}, 
         ylabel={Ordinate label, $gf_{u}(\pi)$ [units]},
    ]
     \addplot [domain=1:1000, ultra thick, color=blue] {x^1.5};
     \node[right, fill=white, rectangle, thin, draw] at (30,7) {GFS Neohellenic};
    \end{loglogaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \mathversion{normal}
    }

    \Sphinx

    \end{document}
```

[image]